# Swift Closure Single Statement Issue

Tags: swift, closures

Here I have a simple snippet to use simple animation with my defined UIView.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) { [weak self] in

    self?.popOverView.center = gesture.locationInView(self?.view)
}
```

Here [weak self] is to avoid reference cycle,and I also use trailing closure to simply the code.Howerver,the compiler is unhappy with that and gives me the wrong message.

```
Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(FloatLiteralConvertible, () -> () -> $T2)'
```

What does $T2 stands for ? And the strange thing is that when there is two or more statements in the closure body, it compiles correctly.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) { [weak self] in
    println()
    self?.popOverView.center = gesture.locationInView(self?.view)
}
```

And I know that if there is only one statement in the closure body, it is automatically returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single statement body in a closure have implicit return, so what happens is that the compiler tries to set the result of this statement:

```
self?.popOverView.center = gesture.locationInView(self?.view)
```

as the return value. You can fix that by adding an explicit `return`

```
self?.popOverView.center = gesture.locationInView(self?.view)
return
```

This happens for single statements only, that's why it works correctly in your 2nd case

More info: [Implicit Returns from Single-Expression Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_157)